# Move array item when rendered on html page

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there a way to move an element rendered in html that is stored inside of an array?

My code generates a new div every time a function is called, that div has an animation class added to it, to make it fall down the screen. Then I need to randomly move its X position by a number of pixels.

```
for (i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
   setInterval(function newRock(item){
     let num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
     let num2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1500);
     const rocks = document.querySelector(".rocks");
     const rock = document.createElement("DIV");
     rocks.appendChild(rock)
     rock.classList.add("rock0");
     rock.classList.add("animate");
     rock.style.left = `${num}px`;
     rock.style.top = `${num2}px`;
     rockArray.push(rock.className);
   classNumber++;
 },10000);
}


setInterval(() => {
 console.log(rockArray)}, 10000)
});

rockArray.forEach((item) => {
 item.style.left = `${num}px`;
});

setInterval(function() {
 let num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
 let num2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);

 document.querySelector(".rock0").style.left =  `${num}px`;
 document.querySelector(".rock1").style.left =  `${num2}px`;
}, 3000);
```

Comment: Please show the full code.

Comment: The .style.left also depends on whether the object's position is relative, absolute, fixed etc. CSS can be tricky.

Comment: A [MCVE] would be of great benefit here.

Comment: The div also needs to have `position:absolute` CSS-property

Comment: so the position is set to absolute and position left is set randomly when the div is created, I just need to change the position again but for every new div in the array.

Answer (score 0):

As long as your position property is not static, relative or absolute - left or right css property will not work.

Answer (score 0):

For the `left` and `right` properties to work, your html element has to be a positioned element. Positioned elements include elements having `position` set to any of the following values: `fixed`, `absolute`, `relative`, or `sticky`.

- When `position` is set to `absolute` or `fixed`, the `left`(`right`) property
  specifies the distance between the element's left(right) edge and the left(right)
  edge of its containing block. (The containing block is the ancestor
  to which the element is relatively positioned.)
- When `position` is set to `relative`, the `left`(`right`) property specifies the
  distance the element's left(right) edge is moved to the right(left) from its
  normal position.
- When `position` is set to `sticky`, the `left`(`right`) property is used to
  compute the sticky-constraint rectangle.
- When `position` is set to `static`, the `left`(`right`) property has no
  effect.

See the following articles:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/left
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/right

**Update:**

Having said that, the `num` in the following code seems to be undefined.

```
rockArray.forEach((item) => {
 item.style.left = `${num}px`;
});
```

What is the origin of `num` in `${num}px`? It seems to be undefined.

Comment: I understand that but, My code works here  `rock.style.left = `${num}px`;` I then want to change the position again rockArray.forEach((item) => {
 item.style.left = `${num}px`;
});

Comment: so num is defined globally `let num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);` I have also tried defining it inside of the function. I don't get any errors when the code runs either...

Comment: Do you mind reproducing this on codepen and then attach the link here?